# For a @GET operation which one to use @QueryParam or @FormParam

Tags: java, rest

I am developing a server side application (not client). I have a list operation where I am using `@GET` and I am passing the parameters as `@QueryParam`. Should I use `@FormParam`? Will it be helpful while developing the client?

Comment: Is the client an HTML form element, or a program?

Comment: Not sure bmargulies :( We are exposed only to server implementation:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@FormParam` annotation will expect the parameter to be in the body of the request as sent by an HTML `form` submit.

An HTTP GET *should* not use a request body. So, keep using `@QueryParam` for `@GET`.

See also:

- [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Thanks for d swift response Thiago Nengri. It helped.