# Rest jax-rx web-service don't get data from Html-form+JQuery

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, forms, http-post

I have Jax-rs with Spring Boot, JQuery, Html templates jn WildFly 10 and 
my @Post and @Put method get null from Html-form.

CustomerResource:

```
@POST
    //@Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createCustomers(@QueryParam("firstname") String firstname,
                                    @QueryParam("lastname") String lastname,
                                    @QueryParam("email") String email,
                                    @QueryParam("dateborn") String dateborn,
                                    @QueryParam("pass") String pass,
                                    @Context UriInfo uriInf
    ){
        CustomersEntity customer = new CustomersEntity();
        customer.setFirstname(firstname);
        customer.setLastname(lastname);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setDateborn(dateborn);
        customer.setPass(pass);
        customerService.save(customer);
        long id = customer.getId();

        URI createdUri = uriInf.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(Long.toString(id)).build();
        return Response.created(createdUri).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateCustomers(@PathParam("id") Long id,

                                @QueryParam("customerFn") String firstname,
                                    @QueryParam("customerLn") String lastname,
                                    @QueryParam("customerEmail") String email,
                                    @QueryParam("customerDb") String dateborn,
                                    @QueryParam("customerPass") String pass
                                   ) {
        CustomersEntity inDb = customerService.findOne(id);
        if (inDb == null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else {
        inDb.setFirstname(firstname);
        inDb.setLastname(lastname);
        inDb.setEmail(email);
        inDb.setDateborn(dateborn);
        inDb.setPass(pass);
        customerService.update(inDb);
        }
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

Html-form:

```
<form id="customerForm" method="POST" action="/customers">

        <div class="mainArea">

            <label>Id:</label>
            <input id="custId" name="id" type="text" disabled="disabled" />

            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custFn" name="customerFn" required="required" />

            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custLn" name="customerLn" />

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custEmail" name="customerEmail" />

            <label>Date Born:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custDb" name="customerDb" />

            <label>Pass:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custPass" name="customerPass" />

            <button id="btnSaveCustomer">Save</button>
            <button id="btnDeleteCustomer">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JQuery:

```
function addCustomer() {
    console.log('addCustomer');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: customerlistURL,// + '/create',
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer created successfully');
            $('#btnDeleteCustomer').show();
            $('#custId').val(data.id);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('addCustomer error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function updateCustomer() {
    console.log('updateCustomer');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: customerlistURL + '/' + $('#custId').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer updated successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('updateCustomer error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function deleteCustomer() {
    console.log('deleteCustomer ' + $('#custId').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: customerlistURL + '/' + $('#custId').val(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Customer deleted successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('deleteCustomer error');
        }
    });
}
```

And in this configuration I get next error:
(@POST):

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
  Подробности: Failing row contains (8, null, null, null, null, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 159 more
```

and same in @PUT

@DELETE and all @GET method work fine.

I tried to use @FormParam with/or @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)/@Consumes(MediaType.AP‌​‌​PLICATION_FORM_URL‌​EN‌​CODED) and I take in both case: "PUT localhost:8080/animals-rest/index/customers/2 415 (Unsupported Media Type)".  Or: "The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded". No, I need a JAX-RS Jersey, not else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflection and study of this issue, I found the answer. Jax-rs Jarsey2 configuration extracts data and data-format from the request body no need to use additional annotations for conversion from the HTML-form:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateCustomers(@PathParam("id") Long id,
                                CustomersEntity customer){
    CustomersEntity existCustomer = customerService.findOne(id);
    if (existCustomer == null){
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else {
        existCustomer.setFirstname(customer.getFirstname());
        existCustomer.setLastname(customer.getLastname());
        existCustomer.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
        existCustomer.setDateborn(customer.getDateborn());
        existCustomer.setPass(customer.getPass());
        customerService.update(customer);
    }
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the POST method in html and accessing it using @QueryParam which will be null because there is not any query parameter to the http request received. You may use @FormParam to access the Parameters. Or in spring like below:

```
 @RequestMapping("createCustomer", method="RequestMethod.POST")
 public Response createCustomers(@ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer customer)
```

Please check below link to use FormParam:[using @FormParam](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/)

check the difference between requestParam and formParam:
[difference between formParam and queryParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074359/difference-between-an-http-query-parameter-and-http-form-parameter)

using spring have lot of inbuilt feature so you dont have get single parameters seperately. Please follow some good tutorial on spring with jquery.